# How do I disable directory browsing?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to disable directory browsing of /galerias folder and all subdirectories

> Index of /galerias/409
>
> ```
> * Parent Directory
> * i1269372986681.jpg
> * i1269372986682.jpg
> * i1269372988680.jpg
> ```

Comment: They mention this in the movie "The Social Network" https://youtu.be/BPazh2kDdvA?t=1m49s

Comment: See this in-depth article "How to disable directory listing on Apache" https://helponnet.com/2021/07/29/apache-disable-directory-listing/

Answer (score 539, accepted):

Create an .htaccess file containing the following line:

```
Options -Indexes
```

That is one option. Another option is editing your apache configuration file.

In order to do so, you first need to open it with the command:

```
vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Then find the line:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

Change that line to:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

Lastly save and exit the file, and restart apache server with this command:

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

(You have a guide with screenshots [here](https://www.hostingride.in/content/how-to-hide-apache-directory-listing-or-indexing).)

Answer (score 368):

The best way to do this is disable it with webserver apache2. In my Ubuntu 14.X - open `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` change from

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

then restart apache by:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

This will disable directory listing from all folder that apache2 serves.

Comment: FYI: by disabling the Indexes , you get message "You don't have permission to access this resource.", 403 error.

Answer (score 60):

Apart from the aformentioned two methods (edit **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf** or add **Options -Indexes** in .htaccess file), here is another one

```
a2dismod autoindex
```

Restart the apache2 server afterwards

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: FYI: by disabling the autoindex, you get message "The requested URL was not found on this server.", 404 error.

Answer (score 34):

Edit/Create an `.htaccess` file inside `/galerias` with this:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Directory browsing is provided by the [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html) module.

Answer (score 28):

You can place an empty file called `index.html` into each directory that you don't want listed. This has several advantages:

- It (usually) requires zero configuration on the server.
- It will keep working, even if the server administrator decides to use "AllowOverride None" in the the server configuration. (If you use `.htaccess` files, this can lead to lots of "Error 500 - internal server error" messages for your users!).
- It also allows you to move your files from one server to the next, again without having to mess with the apache configuration.

Theoretically, the autoindexing might be triggered by a different file (this is controlled by the `DirectoryIndex` option), but I have yet to encounter this in the real world.

Answer (score 21):

One of the important thing is on setting a secure apache web server is to disable directory browsing. By default apache comes with this feature enabled but it is always a good idea to get it disabled unless you really need it.
Open httpd.conf file in apache folder and find the line that looks as follows:

```
Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

then remove word Indexes and save the file. Restart apache. That's it

Answer (score 10):

If you choose to modify your httpd.conf file to solve this and you have multiple Options directives, then you must add a - or a + before each directive.  Example:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
```

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer, just my experience:

On my Ubuntu 12.04 apache2, didn't find `Indexes` in either apache2.conf or httpd.conf, luckily I found it in `sites-available/default`. After removing it, now it doesn't see directory listing.  May have to do it for `sites-available/default-ssl`.

Answer (score 3):

To complete @GauravKachhadiya's answer :

```
IndexIgnore *.jpg
```

means "hide only **.jpg** extension files from indexing.

IndexIgnore directive uses wildcard expression to match against directories and files.

- a star character , it matches any charactes in a string ,eg : foo or foo.extension, in the following example, we are going to turn off the directory listing, no files or dirs will appear in the index :

  IndexIgnore *

Or if you want to hide spacific files , in the directory listing, then we can use

```
IndexIgnore *.php
```

*.php =>  matches a string that starts with any char and ends with .php

The example above hides all files that end with .php

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
```

If it is not work for any reason, try this within your .htaccess file:

```
IndexIgnore *
```

Answer (score 2):

Open Your .htaccess file and enter the following code in

```
Options -Indexes
```

Make sure you hit the ENTER key (or RETURN key if you use a Mac) after entering the "Options -Indexes" words so that the file ends with a blank line.

Answer (score 1):

In Directory Section ( `/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`)

Remove Line  - `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks`

New Line -  `Options FollowSymLinks`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `.htaccess`:

```
IndexIgnore *.jpg
```

Comment: This didn't seem to have any effect for me.  What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

I found another way of doing this with virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/WAMP/Apache24/htdocs/
    ServerName vehiclesspares.com
    <Directory C:/WAMP/Apache24/htdocs/vehiclesspares.com>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

This worked for me on Apache 2.4.54 on my local windows machine with the host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) containing the line:
127.0.0.1 vehiclesspares.com
This configuration also had vehiclesspares.com under the docroot: C:\WAMP\Apache24\htdocs\vehiclesspares.com