# How block access to url directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, download

I have the follow link : www.mysite.com/uploads/file.pdf

I want the user to download the file. But I do not want him vizualize files from this directory. How can I do this?

I'm using PHP and Apache.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "visualize files"? Maybe [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even better use `Options -Indexes` in your .htaccess file

create a file named `.htaccess` on that directory and add `Options -Indexes` as the content of the file. Make sure you hit enter after adding `Options -Indexes`

This will make sure that your directory will not be index able . i.e you can access the file say `www.mysite.com/uploads/file.pdf` but you cannot list all the files in that directory using `www.mysite.com/uploads/`

Answer (score 0):

Adding an empty file called `index.html` into the directory www.mysite.com/uploads/ will prevent the user from being able to see(visualize) the files.

Disabling directory indexes will also work [How do I disable directory browsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing)