# Protect 1000+ html files in directory without editing all of them

Tags: php, html, mysql, web, passwords

I am trying to make my website so that you have to log in in order to view some files. I got the login up and running with mySQL databases and everything is working fine, except that i don't want to manually put edit all my 1000+ html files to check if the user is logged in. I have tried using htaccess, but the popup is so ugly i can't stand it.

Now, the question is, can i password-protect a bunch of files on my website without manually modifying all of them, or can i make the "htaccess login form" look good.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming you have an open directory that's viewable by going to `yoursite.com/directory`?  If so, you can [turn off Directory Indexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing), then use PHP to authenticate the user and output the files in an obtainable format.

Comment: And how would i go about outputting the files?

Comment: Search for "how do I output files in PHP".  There are thousands of articles detailing how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You could put all of your HTML files in a directory outside of the webroot, then refer to them through URL rewriting or a basic querystring variable passed to a single PHP script.

For example:

```
<?php
// Get the file from ?whichfile=(...)
$whichfile = $_GET['whichfile'];

// Put your logic here to verify that the user is logged in / has a valid session ID, etc.
// You should also put some checks on the value that is passed through "whichfile"
// to prevent users from accessing things they shouldn't.

// Edit: example to prevent this:
// $whichfile = "../../../../etc/passwd";

$fname = pathinfo($whichfile, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$ext = pathinfo($whichfile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$fname .= ($ext ? ".".$ext : "");

if (file_exists("/var/www/folder/out/of/webroot/".$fname)) {
   $blob = file_get_contents("/var/www/folder/out/of/webroot/".$fname);
   header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
   print $blob;
}
```

Comment: Be aware when using this answer that this may lead to file system exposure outside the document root, for example when requesting `../../../../../../../etc/passwd`

Comment: @Ferrybig That was the purpose of the comment "// You should also put some checks on the value that is passed through "whichfile" to prevent users from accessing things they shouldn't."  Edited with example.