# Is it possible to redirect someone to a page after browsing a directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I already disabled directory browsing using this method [How do I disable directory browsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing) ..
Now, is it possible for me to redirect it to a particular page?

Ex. `mysite.com/subdirectory/another_directory/` to `mysite.com/sorry.php`

---

okay, i made it.

i just need to do this ..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /client/
php_value upload_max_filesize 15M
php_value post_max_size 15M
#Options -Indexes

RewriteRule ^downloads/files/?$ /sorry.php [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .htaccess:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 15M
php_value post_max_size 15M
#Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /client/

RewriteRule ^downloads/files/?$ /sorry.php [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: it doesn't work.. i still get the 403 forbidden error and i am not redirected to sorry.php

Comment: Can you show your current .htaccess? You need to remove `directory browsing disabling`.

Comment: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /client/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

php_value upload_max_filesize 15M
php_value post_max_size 15M

Options -Indexes
RedirectMatch 301 ^/downloads/files/ /sorry.php`

if i am going to remove `Options -Indexes` .. i can browse now the directory files

Comment: also, when i do what you answer above all my page like index.php as index and edit.php as edit i am now getting 404 not found

Comment: it works.. try to view my updated question... i just need to add `RewriteEngine on`

Comment: Yes I assumed `RewriteEngine On` is already there from your comments. Consider marking the answer as accepted now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47327/discussion-between-user3258603-and-anubhava)

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htaccess` file write:

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /sorry.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: i got 500 internal error with `ErrorDocument 403 /sorry.php [R=301,L]`