# Lock remote directory but not URLs

Tags: php, mysql, permissions, web, directory

I find it difficult to form my question properly, so apologies in advance.
I'm currently building a small web app where users can sign up, log in and upload pictures. These pictures are stored in different directories. I want to be able to lock these directories, so people cannot simply view the entire directory (because it features a picture contest and submissions should remain secret). But I also want the *contents* to be viewable. I intend to create long filenames within the directory automatically to keep them "safe".

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance,
Lenny

Comment: Exactly. When you put it like that, it sounds easy :P I will try your solution immediately.

Answer (score 1):

To disable directory browsing of your files, the simplest way is to add a line to an `.htaccess` file (if you're using Apache) in a common directory:

```
Options -Indexes
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing)

Alternatively you can add this also to a `<Directory>` or `<Location>` section of a vhost entry, but would apply to the entire vhost rather than just a given directory tree.