# symfony2 access control on assets

Tags: symfony

For some reason ( AngularJS top secret js files ) I need to put behind a firewall my resources. But I don't know how to setup that the symfony way.
I already tried to set a access_control on /web/myresources.js but the kernel does not handle it.

I'd like to do something like this :

```
- { path: ^/assets/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

To protect, for example : "/assets/admin/js/app.js".

Any ideas ?
Thank you.

EDIT : 
I created a bundle to achieve that. It is not documented yet, but here is the repo :

https://github.com/NathanVss/resources-firewall-bundle

Comment: What web-server do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Symfony firewall can only work on URIs managed by Symfony. Assets are static files and are not routed through Symfony.

Use web server config to protect such routes. For instance, by protecting [directory index listings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2530372/1149495) in Apache:

> Create a .htaccess file with the following:
>
> ```
> Options -Indexes
> ```

Or by disabling autoindex in [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html):

> ```
> Syntax:  autoindex on | off;
> Default: autoindex off;
> Context: http, server, location
> ```
>
> Enables or disables the directory listing output.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it is good to know :) 
I edited my question :)