# PHP scandir of an url

Tags: php, url, scandir

How can I use scandir with an URL. Now it looks like PHP doesn't see the URL as an URL. Is there a way to use an URL in scandir?

```
<form action="new_exercise.php?id=<?php echo $new_id; ?>" method="post">
        <input class="" type="text" name="name_exe" required placeholder="Project naam">
        <select name="audio" required>
          <option></option>
          <?php
          $path = 'URL comes here';
          $results = scandir($path);
          foreach ($results as $result) {
              if ($result === '.' or $result === '..') continue;

              if (is_dir($path . '/' . $result)) {
                  echo "<option>" . $result . "</option>";
              }
          }
          ?>
        <select>
        <input class="btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Maak nieuwe opdracht">
    </form>
```

Comment: I would certainly hope that scandir doesn't allow this

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't do this with an url. The scandir function accepts a directory path, relative or absolute but you can't pass an URL to this function. This is not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible. `scandir()` and many other file operations only work local.

If you want to get a list of files on a remote server then you need a script/API on the server that will return that file list.

Just imagine what would happen if you could read all files and directories on a remote machine? Security would be realy compromised.

Answer (score 0):

`Scandir` works perfectly for local directory.

> [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) — List files and directories inside the specified path

But you can't get list of files onto server, because in many cases urls are not directly mapping on files (e.g., `location` command of [nginx webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing)). Also webservers usually block possibility of getting list files for directories (see this settings for [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing))