# Permmision Denied when i try to open XML files in PHP

Tags: php, io, simplexml

```
<?php
    $fileNames = scandir("www.boston.com");
    foreach ($fileNames as $value) {

        $xml = simplexml_load_file($value);
        echo $xml->reviews->review->text;
    }
?>
```

> I get " simplexml_load_file(.): failed to open stream: Permission
>   denied..." i am using Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP scandir of an url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840274/php-scandir-of-an-url)