# Deny folder permission that is used by url (www.xxxxxx.com/data/xx.php) or browsing

Tags: php, directory, server-side, chmod, mkdir

How do I do to stop user/client to navigate in some of my website folders using URL like this:

```
www.site.com/main_folder/subfolder_Contaienr/files.php
www.site.com/main_folder/data/files.php
www.site.com/main_folder/data/also_here_text_files.txt
```

With this URL, the user can navigate to my folders and I do not want that he navigate to my website folders.

Also everyday I have some new folders. I use files in folder for external scope (e.g in some folder there are images and need to show users. In some folders are text files in which is JSON data or some users details.)

Is there any way to stop navigate to my folders ***using php Code*** without touching `.htacess` file?

Comment: do you need those files to be externally accessible (e.g. should they be available via the web?) If not, then the SAFEST and EASIEST option is to move them outside of your site's document root. in other words, if they shouldn't be visible, then don't make them available.

Comment: yes they are externally accessible. and i also update my question. :)

Comment: Are you running Apache? Is it correct to say that you want to prevent access to `main_folder` and everything inside of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable directory browsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing)

Comment: then password protect the folders, if you do need access but need to deny them to others. and/or put them in an obscure URL as well, so the path isn't visible/guessable.

Comment: @ccKep That won't stop direct URL access to specific files...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: He said he needs them accessible (for example, images that need to be shown to the user). I think he just doesn't want his users to browse the directory so easily.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus 1.) yes. i am running  apache in windows 7(localhost).  -  2.) no not only `main_folder` also some oter folders also like `data`

Comment: @ccKep Sorry about that, I didn't see the edit made by OP.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus No worries, I'm not 100% certain what OPs asking aswell. The question could use some clarification.

Comment: @ccKep its all in question what i am asking.. How do i stop users to  naviagte to certain folders and them subfolders only i can do using php code or maually...? do i have to use any permission mode ?

Comment: @Aryan It really isn't. Even after your edits. Simple answer: You cannot affect a request on `/main_folder/data/also_here_text_files.txt` form inside some other PHP file. Apache opens the file directly and serves it to the user, the only way to influence that behaviour is to setup your apache correctly (either by using .htaccess files or in the configs directly). If you don't want that file accessible from the web, do as @MarcB told you and move it out of the document root.

Comment: @ccKep Agreed, check out my answer though :)

Comment: ok ty for  answer. so i use htacess to doit.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your website actually requires quite a bit of restructuring in order to achieve your goal properly but this `.htaccess` file can be a temporary, ahem *tempermanent*, band-aid in the root of your site which will deny access to all files except for whitelisted extensions:

**www.example.com/.htaccess**

```
Options -Indexes // Turn off directory listings
order allow,deny // Deny all file access
<Files ~ "\.(php|html|js|css|jpg|png|gif|ico|txt|pdf)$"> // separate file extension with a pipe |
   allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: This answer would allow access to exactly the files the OP is asking to deny? (eg. the .txt files in the data folder etc.) So it actually wouldn't do anything for him?

Comment: @ccKep In all honesty I am still unclear of OP's request. Maybe `html|js|css|jpg|png|gif|ico` would suffice...

Comment: I think he has files he doesn't want to be accessible from the web **at all**, which is impossible without restructuring his document root (and probably application) or using .htaccess files. He (originally) asked to do it without any of those though.

Comment: @ccKep You're right but I don't think OP's requirements will ever become fully ascertainable. Based on their final comment on the question, it sounds like he might go with my suggested route though, lol.