# why is folder /static is visible and accesible in Flask? How do I hide it?

Tags: flask

How do I prevent mysite.com/static from being visible and accessible for everyone? I discovered that it's accessible by accident.

I am using Flask and Python3.

I don't know how to prevent this.

Comment: Are you running flask with the built in web server?

Comment: I am using Apache2 and wod-wsgi to run server, and Flask as web framework.

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing

Comment: Flask recommends that a static folder be served by your web server (Apache in your case), but also has the capability of serving static files. There must either be a rule in your apache configuration or a view in your flask app that is allowing access to the static folder.

Answer (score 0):

Flask creates the `/static/<filename>` route by default.

You can prevent that by setting `static_folder` to None when you instantiate Flask:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder=None)
```