# Hide directory listing when accessing public folders in the browser

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, zend-framework2, directory-listing

How can I restrict access to my zend framework 2 public folder for example the `css` folder? I would like to hide the directory listing that shows up when I access a folder via `http`. But I want that the files can be utilized properly by the application.

This directory list shows up when I access the `css` folder on my domain:

[image]

Virtual Host Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server1.jobsoft.co
    ServerAlias server1.jobsoft.co
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/engsvc_dev/public
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/engsvc_dev.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/engsvc_dev.common.log common

    <Directory /var/www/html/engsvc_dev/public>

            DirectoryIndex index.php
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all

    </Directory>
```

My `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?server1.jobsoft.co$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/engsvc_dev/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?server1.jobsoft.co$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /public/index.php [L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `css` files normally need to be publicly accessible. What do you mean with *"utilize properly by the application"*. If you mean use it in your client sided application/code, then it needs to be publicly accessible. If you mean you want to use it in your server side code then I suggest you remove this file from the public folder.

Comment: i dont  want to show the structure on the browser, or is that not possible?

Comment: Check [here](https://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/prevent-directory-listing-htaccess.shtml) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited your question and added the term "directory listing" because this is how this list of files that shows on your screen is commonly called. At first I didn't know what you wanted after reading your question. But after your comment I got it.

Normally you can prevent directory-listing by adding an additional rule to your the `.htaccess` file for your Apache server.

You can find lots of posts on how to do this, for example [here](https://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/prevent-directory-listing-htaccess.shtml) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing) or many more [by searching the topic on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=disable%20directory%20listing).

The magic is turned off by:

```
Options -Indexes
```

And turned on by

```
Options +Indexes
```

In [this apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html) you can read the following in the chapter **Options Directive**:

> **Indexes**
>   If a URL which maps to a directory is requested and there is no `DirectoryIndex` (e.g., `index.html`) in that directory, then `mod_autoindex` will return a formatted listing of the directory.