# Virtual host shows directory structure

Tags: php, macos, laravel, virtualhost

> **Goal** :- set up virtual host correctly.

currently I am working on MAC system version 10.10.05 os x yosemite.

I have configured apache2,php and mysql using [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

I have follow [all the necessary steps](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/set-virtual-hosts-apache-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks-osx-10-8-mountain-lion/) for configuring virtual host.

my file **/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf** would be like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName emsv2l.localhost.com
    ServerAlias emsv2l.localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/emsv2"
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/apple.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/apple.com-access_log" common
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dev.plutustec.com
        <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/emsv2">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName emsv2l-backend.plutustec.com
    ServerAlias emsv2l-backend.plutustec.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/emsv2-backend/public“
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/apple.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/apple.com-access_log" common
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dev.plutustec.com
        <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/emsv2-backend/public“>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So, Now if i write `http://emsv2l.localhost.com/` would be redirect to project instead it's showing directory structure.

[image]

my `/etc/hosts` file would be like

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
#127.0.0.1      localhost
#255.255.255.255        broadcasthost
#::1             localhost
#127.0.0.1      dev.local
#127.0.0.1     emsv2l-backend.plutustec.com             # emsv2-backend
#127.0.0.1     emsv2l.plutustec.com             # emsv2
#127.0.0.1      plutustec.com #localplutus site
127.0.0.1 emsv2l.localhost.com
127.0.0.1 emsv2l-backend.plutustec.com
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have access to apache service? You might need to restart apache.

Comment: many time i have restart apache using XAMPP gui.

Comment: @ShashankShah can you show us your files under `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/emsv2` is there any index.* file there?

Comment: I think in Apache, the order of virtual hosts also matters + there was something like `VirtualHostName 127.0.0.1`. If you want a more logical and easier setup, use nginx.

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable directory listing, to do that replace this:

```
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/emsv2">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

With:

```
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/emsv2">
        Options FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then **reload apache**.

For more details check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445273/1016425)

Then one more thing, do you have an index.php or index.html within your: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/emsv2`?

Comment: Indexing should not be required to turn off. It might actually be something you want to use. But indeed check for an index.* file

Comment: I have tried above but it's not working changed content of the file and restart apache.

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the guide for configuring vhosts to the letter?
If so, are you sure that the Apache you configured is the one that is currently listening on port 80?
XAMPP should have it's own Apache built in and it doesn't run off the default config.
Your XAMPP httpd.conf should contain:

```
# XAMPP VirtualHosts dir
Include /Applications/XAMPP/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

To solve fastest just:

```
cp -iv /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf /Applications/XAMPP/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

If asked for overwrite confirmation press 'y'

Answer (score 0):

in my case,

i'm using macOS Mojave (Apache/2.4.34). In /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file search for the text "IfModule dir_module". Check the IfModule directive/tag contain any index.php. If no the add index.php after index.html. Hope this will save you.

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```