# php and mysql - is this secure?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am currently developing a website and a web app (different code) that will share the same data, and this data is stored inside a database. I made it this way:

I have two domains

> Domain 1 -> contains the utilities (ie. php files to query the db)
>
> Domain 2 -> contains the website

from `domain2` i send a request to `http://domain1.com/utilities/php/domain2/get_from_db.php` and this gives me back the result i need.

My fear is that this is no secure, as the files are somehow exposed?

It used to be an empty website, and if you were to navigate to http://domain1.com/ the file structure was visible. I now created an empty `index.php` file, so that the file structure is not visible anymore.

I have the impression this is still not really secure, am i correct?

the database files are the following:

> config.ini
>
> get_from_db.php

the `get_from_db.php` has this code to connect and get the data back from the db:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain2.com");
$db = new mysqli($host, $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['dbName');

if ($db->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


class data
{
    public $id = "";
    public $col1 = "";
    public $col2 = "";
    public $col3 = "";
    public $col4 = "";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM myDb.myTable";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));

$obj = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $col1 = $row['col1'];
    $col2 = $row['col2'];
    $col3 = $row['col3'];
    $col4 = $row['col4'];

    $e = new cvdata();
    $e->col1 = $skills;
    $e->col2 = $hobbies;
    $e->col3 = $education;
    $e->col4 = $experience;
    array_push($obj, $e);

}

echo json_encode($obj);
```

now, my final question is:

Is this level of security enough? (I mean, I know about login and so on, but this is a very simple project and the data should be available to everyone tries to use the website or the app as it is not sensitive at all (it is just some project's details, that's all))

Thanks for any help, suggestion or advice

Comment: Regarding part of your question - you should be able to configure your web server to not list the contents of directories. In Apache, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing

Comment: Are you sending requests to domain1 from scripts that run on the domain2 client or server? If they're coming from the server, you can use a simple password-style authentication in the requests. If they're coming from the client, you need something more complicated, to prevent users from capturing the traffic and spoofing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how sensitive your data is. If we're talking about pretty serious data, I'd try to use a `JWT`-esque token authorization system, but if it's just minor things, like e.g. the menu card of a restaurant, I'd set `domain2` to be the only one capable of making `cross-origin HTTP requests` and be done with it.

What you however ***should*** do is take the `config.ini` out of your visible path. Lower it to a level where it's only accessible through the filesystem, but not via `http://domain2.com/config.ini`

Comment: the only possible way to access config.ini is via http://domain1.com/utilities/php/domain2/config.ini - How can i take it out from my visible path? where's the best place to put this files like this in 
a server?

Comment: In your folder structure, you should have a folder named `httpdocs` or `www`, or something like that. Everything within that folder is accessible to the public (if not secured).  What I usually do is create a folder called `config` on the same level as that `www` folder. So it's findable for me, through the filesystem, but not via a browser. @Nick