# prevent root directory access publicly for my domain

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, .htaccess

Actually i have a website www.domain.com

when i tried to inspect element and try to access **www.domain.com/css/** then it showed all the files in the directory

Structure

- /css/
- /images/
- /include/
- /js/
- index.html
- contact.html
- sitemap.xml
- style.css
- robot.txt
- .htaccess

i want css,images,include,js folder to be protected means if anyone try to access **www.domain.com/images/** then he should be redirected to **www.domain.com/index.html** rest index.html,contact.html,sitemap,robot.txt should be publicly accessible and **www.domain.com/images/abcd.jpg** can be publicly accessible but **www.domain.com/images/** should not be publicly accessible.

can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: put a blank `index.html` file in all folders. If you want to do that by htaccess then put `Options -Indexes `.

Comment: use htaccess to redirect to index.html

Comment: It is better to handle it with 403 forbidden, instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable directory browsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable directory listing with this option in your server config or in .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Details here: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings

To redirect the user to your homepage, use a rewrite rule or put a redirect in your HTTP 403/404 error page.