# Deny access to a folder from direct url

Tags: php, .htaccess

So I've found many posts here on how to do a similar action, however, I'm still confused. So here is my question. I want to have access to www.mywebsite/folder/index.html but if I were to remove the index.html and just type in www.mywebsite/folder/ I don't want to have access to that. How can I go about doing this? I read that I can use an .htaccess file with *deny from all* but that restricts me from the whole folder and I can't access the index.html.

Please let me know if there is a solution or another post that I missed that outlines the exact situation.

Thank you!

Comment: unusual request, but i was thinking `DirectoryIndex zzzzzzzzzzzz` make sure there is no zzzzzzzzzzzz file

Comment: where do they go if they put nothing in?  404 error page?  to me this would make it seem like your site is broken, I think its a bad idea from usability view.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing

Comment: @AaronMuslim awesome, thank you. I got it to work. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable directory browsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which Apache version are you using? In 2.4, you can use [`DirectoryIndex disabled`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) to stop it from automatically serving up the index.html, and combine that with [`Options -Indexes`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options).

In lower versions `disabled` does not exist yet, so using mod_rewrite with a simple RewriteRule that forbids access when the exact folder path (with or without trailing slash) was requested should do it,

```
RewriteRule ^folder/?$ - [F,L]
```

To control what error message the user gets to see in each case, specify the [`ErrorDocument`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument) for the 403 Forbidden status code.