# how to avoid giving 777 permission

Tags: php, linux, permissions

I have a PHP Script running on Linux that requires 777 Permission to write into folders but this permission is such a risky one is there a way out to avoid that permission instead of the ability to write?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, set the correct owner and group for the directory. Then you can set the permission only for the user or group

Comment: Use `chown`. Depends of your configuration, if Apache: `chown www-data:www-data folder`.

Comment: @dan08 the home directory owned by the account user and the group is user nobody from apache...

Comment: @Syscall do I have to change the owner of the home directory to nobody or have to change the permission of nobody user?

Comment: Do not change the permission of user, change owner of the directory. `nobody` is the user of the caller of PHP?

Comment: @Syscall yes it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make that directory owned by your php script, likely by chown for www-data:www-data, and then assign 755, so only web user can write to it. Obviously, block directory listing on your web server for that directory.

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: @CatChMeIfUCan - imagine that php script writes to /var/www/foo, then I would do: sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/foo, followed by sudo chmod 755 /var/www/foo, followed by editing /etc/apache2/apache2.conf from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445273/2001405