# Deny access to directories but allow files within using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, directory

So I'm looking for a way to deny access to my directories (dir1, dir2, dir99999) but I want others still be able to access the files within these directories (so the .jpg's).

As a clarification, here is the structure I'm talking about:

```
cdn.mydomain.com/dir1/dir1.jpeg
cdn.mydomain.com/dir2/dir2.jpeg
...
cdn.mydomain.com/dir99999/dir99999.jpeg
```

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: if you want disable directory browsing [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing)

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find that topic. `Options -Indexes` worked for me.