# How to change sub directory folder to default login page in PHP using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a root folder and I have created a sub folder as admin. When ever I type url as http://localhost/website/admin/ it is showing all files present in the directory. I don't want that particular folder instead I want default as login page. How can I do that.

I want output like :
 http://localhost/website/admin/login.php as default page
instead of
 http://localhost/website/admin/

Comment: You might find answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Method 1

Use `DirectoryIndex` in .htaccess. Firstly create file named .htaccess in the `/website/admin` folder. And add this line to the .htaccess file.

```
DirectoryIndex login.php
```

## Method 2

Create index.php in the `/website/admin` folder. And redirect to `login.php` using it.

```
<?php
  header('Location: http://example.com/website/admin/login.php');
?>
```