# Hide a folders content but leave the files accessible

Tags: php, linux, centos, cpanel

A script on my website uploads images to `mysite.com/uploads` and generates a path to the image uploaded like `mysite.com/uploads/123456789.jpg`.

The image should only to visible to users with a path to the file. The folder shouldn't list out its contents.

The script is built using PHP and runs on a Linux system (CentOS) managed by cPanel. I am new to Linux and I don't understand how this can be done and I need your help with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable directory browsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing)

Answer (score 4):

I beleive that's not PHP issue. If you using Apache webserver you need a `.htaccess` file in that folder with the following content:

```
Options -Indexes
```

And also you can try simply add empty file `index.html` in each directory you'd like to hide.

Comment: Thanks! That's another thing I wanted to ask, does adding the index file automatically hide directory contents? I understand it how it would work in my browser but say on a command line.

Comment: I do not know if I understood the question correctly =) In general, it does not hide the contents at all. When a client requests a folder to the server, the server simply does not give the list. But if you need to get it in the console - it will of course be available. For example, the console command `cd path/to/uploads && ls` return all files list.

Comment: And if you adding an empty `index.html` - then request to `yoursite.com/uploads/` returned that empty index file =)