# How to disable the download of files in an Apache2 webserver?

Tags: apache

I took over a website which I'm supposed to admin and somebody brought to my attention that certain Indexes and Files are available, which shouldn't be. I will be using dummy names.

You were able to access `example.com/intern` before, but I changed a line in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` according to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445273 . This worked partly, as I get a 403-Forbidden when I now navigate to `example.com/intern` and that's basically what I want.

However the directory `intern` governs a file called `file.php.bak` aswell as `file.php`. When I navigate to `example.com/intern/file.php` I get a white website. I am however not sure, if you are able to access `file.php` in another way, because the site does load and I don't get a 403 like before. What is way worse and the reason I am struggling with this is: If I go to `example.com/intern/file.php.bak` then my Browser (Firefox) offers me to download `file.php.bak`, which I can read in plaintext. I want all files in `intern` to not be accessible via the website, but I have no idea how to do this. Can anybody help?

Things I've tried:

1. Removing the Indexes from the `apache2.conf` file like mentioned above. It only puts the 403 on the directory itself and not recursively for all the files in it.
2. Writing a `.htaccess` file as described here: https://fedingo.com/how-to-prevent-direct-file-download-in-apache-server/ and putting it in `intern` with the same result as in 1)
3. Putting an empty `index.html` file in the `intern` directory. This leads to no more 403 in `example.com/intern`, but the download on `example.com/intern/file.php.bak` is still possible. I've also tried `index.php` with the same result.

File System:

The application runs from `/var/www/application` which is also the folder for the `/var/www/application/index.php` I want to use. The `/var/www/application/intern` directory is also there. While it isn't browsable anymore, the files in it still are accessible. `/var/www/application/intern/file.php` can be navigated to via `example.com/intern/file.php`, but it seems like it can't be downloaded or read as it results in a white page. `/var/www/application/intern/file.php.bak` can however be downloaded via `example.com/intern/file.php.bak`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say Apache document root is set to DocumentRoot "**/folder_one/folder_two**"

Placing files in a **folder_one** will prevent people browsing your apache server and requesting the files directly.

Place index file in **folder_two** and include some code such as PHP to tell apache to include whatever files you want from **folder_one**.

In this manor Apache will still be able to serve whatever files you want from **folder_one** and people will not be able to request the files directly as the are located in a directory above the Apache document root.